# Failed to connect before the deadline with nodejs application on armv7 with Debian

Tags: node.js, debian, hyperledger-fabric, armv7, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am using a beaglebone-black armv7 with a Debian image as an HLF nodejs client application.
The application uses fabric-client, fabric-ca-client, fabric-network node modules and is built as a rest API called by the client (using curl for testing), then the API works as a gateway to the HLF Network thanks to a connection-profile configuration.

The problem is that the exact same application (with the exact same connection-profile) works fine in my Ubuntu machine (it communicates with a network deployed in an AWS instance) **BUT**, when working on the armv7 with Debian, the client **EVEN** if it manages to successfully enroll (docker logs from the CA container confirm that) is not able to communicate with peers when invoking or querying the chaincode `"Error: Failed to connect before the deadline".`

I do not understand why I am getting this error that could depend on the difference between my Ubuntu machine and my embedded Debian device or also due to settings or configuration that I am not aware of.

Clearly the node-module for the Debian is correctly compiled since I used npm install on the Debian device itself starting from the package.json.

Below the errors that I am receiving.

#### CLIENT SIDE:

```sh
curl http://localhost:3000/myBalance/ArmClient
{"error":{"message":"No peers available to query. Errors: [\"Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051\",\"Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051\"]","stack":"FabricError: No peers available to query. Errors: [\"Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051\",\"Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051\"]\n    at SingleQueryHandler.evaluate (/home/debian/Arm/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/singlequeryhandler.js:44:17)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)","name":"FabricError"}}
```

#### API SIDE:

```sh
2019-11-01T16:03:38.658Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051
2019-11-01T16:03:38.661Z - warn: [Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer1.org1.example.com:8051" failed: message=Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051, stack=Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051
    at checkState (/home/debian/Arm/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:835:16), connectFailed=true
2019-11-01T16:03:41.719Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2019-11-01T16:03:41.721Z - warn: [Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer0.org1.example.com:7051" failed: message=Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051, stack=Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051
    at checkState (/home/debian/Arm/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:835:16), connectFailed=true
2019-11-01T16:03:41.724Z - error: [SingleQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=No peers available to query. Errors: ["Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051","Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051"], stack=FabricError: No peers available to query. Errors: ["Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051","Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051"]
    at SingleQueryHandler.evaluate (/home/debian/Arm/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/singlequeryhandler.js:44:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7), name=FabricError
Failed to evaluate transaction: FabricError: No peers available to query. Errors: ["Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:8051","Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051"]
```